# how to speed up the code for splitting file on first column

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy  
import pandas as pd  
import math as m
import os
import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime


final = "D:/Technical_Data/final.csv"

group_col_indx = 0
group_col = pd.read_csv(final, usecols=[group_col_indx])
keys = group_col.iloc[:,0].unique()

for key in keys:
    df_list = []
    print key
    reader = pd.read_csv(final, chunksize=20000)
    for chunk in reader:
        good_rows = chunk[chunk.iloc[:,group_col_indx] == key]
        df_list.append(good_rows)
    df_key = pd.concat(df_list)
    file_save = "D:/Technical_Data_by_Date/" + str(key) + ".csv"
    df_key.to_csv(file_save, header=False,index=False)
```

With the help of stack overflow and google I came up with code to split a large file into multiple file using 1st column.
I am running it on my machine which have 8 gb of RAM. The program is running very slow . How can I speed it up? I did research for past 2 days and this is the script I came up with it

Comment: How many output files do you expect to have? Would it be reasonable to keep them all open at once?

Comment: @tdelaney The number of output files is huge around 600. in future it will go upto 3000.

Comment: is using groupby over iterator better idea?

Comment: @nnnnmmm, may your key column be quoted with double quotes? It would be also helpful if you would provide a sample of your key column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although i do love pandas i wouldn't use it in this case, because you don't seem to want to process your data, just split it up. So if you just want to split your CSV file by key (date) you can simply use [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) for that:

Assuming that your key is in the second column `$2` (change `$2` --> `$1` if your key column is in the first column)...

prg.awk

```
{
    key = $2
    print > "D:/Technical_Data_by_Date/"key".csv"
}
```

command:

```
gawk -F"," -f prg.awk final.csv
```

It will work **much** faster

If you by all means want to use python + pandas - make sure you read your input CSV file **ones** (currently you do it `number of keys + 1` times, i.e. approx. 601 times):

```
import pandas as pd

fn = 'D:/Technical_Data/final.csv'
sep=','
out_path = 'D:/Technical_Data_by_Date'
chunk_size = 20000
key_col_idx = 0

reader = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=sep, chunksize=chunk_size)

for chunk in reader:
    # loop through keys
    for key in chunk.iloc[:, key_col_idx].unique():
        # writing (appending: mode='a') data to CSV files (by key)
        chunk[chunk.iloc[:, key_col_idx] == key] \
             .to_csv('{0}/{1}.csv'.format(out_path, key),
                     mode='a', header=None, index=False)
```

PS the trick is to use `mode='a'` parameter when calling `.to_csv()` method, which will append data to CSV file instead of overwriting it

PPS it will be slower compared to AWK solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be faster, but since you have too many output files to keep open at once, you could open files in groups. This will reduce the number of times you need to scan the input file. Here, I'm just doing the read line by line and do multiple rewind-read-write cycles. You could speed it up a bit if your csv is simple, allowing a simple `split` on the first comma to find the key instead of using the bulky csv module.

if not faster... its at least a data point to tell you whether the `pandas` game is worth it.

```
import os
import csv

final = "D:/Technical_Data/final.csv"
outdir = "D:/Technical_Data_by_Date"
maxfiles = 128

with open(final) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, buffering=32*1024*1024)

    # scan file for keys
    keys = list(set(row[0] for row in reader))

    # scan and write 'maxfiles' at a time
    for keyidx in range(0, len(keys), maxfiles):
        keygrp = keys[keyidx:keyidx+maxfiles]
        outcsvs = {}
        outfps = []
        try:
            # open next group of output files
            for key in keygrp:
                fp = open(os.path.join(outdir, "{}.csv".format(key)), 
                    "w", newline='', buffering=1024*1024)
                outcsvs[key] = csv.writer(fp)
                outfps.append(fp)            
            # rewind input and extract rows
            infile.seek(0)
            for row in reader:
                writer = outcsvs.get(row[0])
                if writer:
                    writer.writerow(row)
        finally:
            for fp in outfps:
                fp.close()
```